# mat-grid-lists in angular materia overflowing each other vertically when zoomed out in angular 15 project

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am using mat-grid-list in my project to display charts within cards in each row. The contents inside the cards are responsive. However, when the screen size becomes smaller (or when zoomed out), the mat-grid-lists overflows vertically. I am new to Angular Material. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the HTML:

```
        <mat-grid-tile
            [colspan]="1"
            [rowspan]="1"
            class="mat-grid"

        >
            <mat-card class="chart-card">
                <mat-card-content class="chart-card-content">
                    <h1 class="fnt-x chart-title fnt-x font-secondary">Net Churn Rate Month Wise</h1> 
                    <app-multiline-chart> </app-multiline-chart>         
                </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile
            [colspan]="1"
            [rowspan]="1"
            class="mat-grid"
        >
            <mat-card class="chart-card">
                <mat-card-content class="chart-card-content">
                    <h1 class="fnt-x chart-title fnt-x font-secondary"> ARPU Month Wise</h1>
                    <app-line-chart2> </app-line-chart2>         
                </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
        </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-container">
    <mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="700px">
        <mat-grid-tile
            [colspan]="1"
            [rowspan]="1"
            class="mat-grid"
        >
            <mat-card class="chart-card">
                <mat-card-content class="chart-card-content">
                    <h1 class="fnt-x chart-title fnt-x font-secondary"> ARPU Month Wise</h1>  
                    <app-stacked-barchart [data]="stacked_data"></app-stacked-barchart> 
            
                </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
        </mat-grid-tile>  
</mat-grid-list>
  <mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="700px">
    <mat-grid-tile
        [colspan]="1"
        [rowspan]="1"
        class="mat-grid"
    >
        <mat-card class="chart-card">
            <mat-card-content class="chart-card-content">
                <h1 class="fnt-x chart-title fnt-x font-secondary"> Churned Subs Age Network</h1>  
               <app-horizontal-bar-chart></app-horizontal-bar-chart> 
            </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>  
  </mat-grid-list>
```

And here is the css:

```
.container {
    margin-top: 4rem;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
}
.container:: -webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 0px; 
}
```

```
.mat-grid-list {
    height: calc(620px) !important;
    margin-bottom: 20px;    
}

.chart-card {
    border: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow-x:visible;
    

}

.chart-card-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.chart-title {
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
.mat-form-field {
    margin-left: 18px;
}
```

I want the grid list in each row to have a margin-bottom and should not affect other grids when zooming out. I tried changing the rowHeight and rows attribute, But it is not fixing the issue.